# Sharepoint 2013: Not able to bulk edit checkbox columns in custom list

Tags: 2013, custom-list, choice-field, quick-edit

I have a custom sharepoint list that we are inputting data into. (SharePoint 2013.) This is a fresh list and was not migrated over from any other version of SharePoint.

Everything can be edited through Quick Edit, except for columns that have checkboxes. I have attempted to quick edit through a Standard View, and a Datasheet View. I can edit any other type of column, but when I try to edit the checkbox, that cell gets greyed out.

I checked the view, and the "Allow individual item checkboxes" is selected under *Tabular View*.

There is no Groupings under *Group By*.

*Style* is set to "Default". I tried switching to a different style, saving, and switching back to "Default" and saving. No dice.

Everything else is set to defaults as far as I can see.

There are no workflows for this list.

Why am I unable to edit checkbox columns in Quick Edit mode in Standard view, or with a Datasheet view?

EDIT: With further testing, I see that a checkbox cell becomes read-only if you enable *Allow 'Fill-in' choices* for that multi-choice column. Pretty funky. Is there anyway around quick editing a checkbox column that allows Fill-in options? I would rather not have to open up every single item in order to edit that column.

Answer (score 2):

It's by design, In Quick Edit, unfortunately, you can't  `Allow 'Fill-in' choices` with  `Checkboxes (allow multiple selections)`

[image]

There is no explicit workaround to do this, but in bulk edit, you should choose between the following options

- `Checkboxes (allow multiple selections)` without  `Allow 'Fill-in' choices`, or
- `Drop-Down Menu` with  `Allow 'Fill-in' choices`.

Comment: Weird, as on a separate 2010 SharePoint server we are able to edit checkboxes with fill-ins. Oh, Microsoft!

Comment: you are welcome, please set it as an answer if it helped you, it's the true sign beside my answer also check this to get informed badge  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour